# Looks like binomial expansion but all coefficients equal 1?

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials

Is there a way to express an equation in terms of $n$ where it looks like binomial expansion except the coefficients of that expansion are all equal to 1?

Something similar to the following...

$n=0 \rightarrow 1$

$n=1 \rightarrow x+y$

$n=2 \rightarrow x^2+xy+y^2$

$n=3 \rightarrow x^3+x^2y+xy^2+y^4$

$n=4 \rightarrow x^4+x^3y+x^2y^2+xy^3+y^4$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_homogeneous_symmetric_polynomial

Comment: Welcome to mathematics stack exchange.  Consider $(x^n-y^n)/(x-y)$

Comment: $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n x^{i}y^{n-i}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $$f_n(x)=1+x+x^2+x^3+..+x^n.$$
This is written in summation notation as 
$$f_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^k.$$
We see that the functions you seek are given by 
$$p_n(x,y)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^ky^{n-k}=y^nf_n(x/y).$$
We see that 
$$f_{n+1}(x)=x^{n+1}+f_n(x),$$
as well as $$xf_n(x)=f_{n+1}(x)-1.$$
Thus $$xf_n(x)=x^{n+1}-1+f_n(x),$$
which is $$f_n(x)=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}\qquad x\ne 1.$$
Then we have 
$$\begin{align}
p_n(x,y)&=y^n\frac{(x/y)^{n+1}-1}{x/y-1}\\
&=\frac{x^{n+1}/y-y^{n}}{x/y-1}\\
&=\frac{(x^{n+1}-y^{n+1})/y}{(x-y)/y}\\
&=\frac{x^{n+1}-y^{n+1}}{x-y}\qquad x\ne y.
\end{align}$$